# How do I get the calculator button on my Microsoft Keyboard to work in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, shortcuts, calculator, gnome-calculator

So I have tried looking through the shortcuts menu and I tried installing the Gnome Calculator and I still can't get it to work. I'm new to Kubuntu and I'm still learning how it works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the keypress give any result? Use `xev` on command line and press the key. If it does NOT give a response... not gonna happen (I have 7 dead keys too: P1 - P6 and the HP Omen key that do nothing at all :( ) Problem is likely with the BIOS support  by our kernel.

Comment: So, this is what the terminal gives me when I press the calculator button:
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x4df, subw 0x0, time 21215923, (-41,92), root:(607,121),
    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x4df, subw 0x0, time 21216004, (-41,92), root:(607,121),
    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: How did you install gnome-calculator? What does `apt policy gnome-calculator` show?

Answer (score 6):

I installed *gnome-calculator* on Kubuntu 18.04 using `sudo apt install gnome-calculator`.

Unfortunately, my keyboard has just 101 keys and so I don't have a Calculator key. Instead, I'll use <kbd>F7</kbd> to illustrate:

- Right-click on the Menu icon in your panel (marked with an arrow in the image below). You'll see a context menu with some entries but the relevant one is *Edit Applications …*:

[image: Edit Applications]

- On opening *Edit Applications …*, you'll get the *KDE Menu Editor*. *gnome-calculator* is listed in the left pane under *Utilities* on my system. Left-click on it. Some details will now appear in the right pane:

[image: KDE Menu Editor]

- Now, click on the *Advanced* tab above the right pane. You'll see *Current shortcut key*. In the field to its right, single left-click and then press the key (or key combination) you wish to use. I've pressed <kbd>F7</kbd>:

[image: Setting a shortcut key to launch gnome-calculator]

- Click the *Save* button near the top left of the *KDE Menu Editor* window. Now, any time you press <kbd>F7</kbd> (or whatever you've chosen), *gnome-calculator* will launch.
- Note that if I press <kbd>F7</kbd> repeatedly, I'll get several windows of *gnome-calculator*.
- To fix that, I can modify the command (in the *General* tab of *KDE Menu Editor*) from just `gnome-calculator` to

  `wmctrl -ax gnome-calculator.Gnome-calculator || gnome-calculator`
- Now, anytime I press <kbd>F7</kbd>, if *gnome-calculator* is open, it'll be brought into focus. If it isn't open, it will be launched. (You'll need to install *wmctrl* on your system using `sudo apt install wmctrl`.)

---

By the way, Kubuntu's calculator is *KCalc* and is part of the default installation.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I did it the hard way, through the global shortcuts menu. I was working on this for a while. I just want to thank everyone for the help!
FYI, I went into system settings, then clicked on shortcuts, then global shortcuts, then the + button, clicked utilities and selected Kcalc (Which I like better than the Gnome counterpart) and then clicked ok and then on the far right, under global, i clicked custom and set the calculator key as the shortcut and rebooted.

Comment: Not sure about Kubuntu 20.04, but KDE neon 5.21.1 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) ships by default with Plasma's `Calculator`, which is different from KCalc, and which can be invoked with `plasmawindowed org.kde.plasma.calculator`.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Kubuntu 21.10 using MS Wireless Keyboard 850. Thanks!